# Java Simple Guessing Game GameZone

Tags: java

Having issues with trying to get this to run and ask the user for their guess, then if it's too low, it states too low, or too high, or correct. Then states what the number was. This is the code I have so far.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class RandomGuess2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int random;

        final int MIN = 1;
        final int MAX = 10;

        int userNum;
        String userInput;

        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please guess a number between 1 and 10");
        random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * MAX);
        userNum = Integer.valueOf(userInput);
        int userDiff = (random - userNum);

        if (userDiff < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO HIGH");

            if (userDiff > 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO LOW");        
            if (userNum == random) 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Your guess of " + userNum + " is correct! Congratulations!");
            else 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number was " + random + "\nTry again Next time!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: ok, and what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The Reason it wasn't working was because your checking was wrong it needs to be like this

```
if (userNum == random){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Your guess of " + userNum + " is correct! Congratulations!");
    }
    else{

        if (userDiff < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO HIGH");
        }
        if (userDiff > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO LOW");
        }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number was " + random + "\nTry again Next time!");
    }
```

yours was checking first to see if the usernum was too high and if it was then it would check to see if the usernum was correct or to too low but that code only ran if the num was too high.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-else-structure is not right. I guess this is what you want:

```
if (userDiff < 0) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO HIGH");
} else if (userDiff > 0) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is TOO LOW");
}

if (userNum == random) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess of " + userNum + " is correct! Congratulations!");
} else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number was " + random + "\nTry again Next time!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! Got it fixed and corrected. I appreciate all the help!